# Display Multiple Markers in Array - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How can I clean this so that the code handles multiple listings better? I have seen some code examples that pull the marker info from an array, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The markers need to have "icon:", "url:" and "title:" attributes. The "icon:" so I can change each markers appearance, the "url:" to point through to the page dedicated to each marker and the "title" just to add the markers name on hover.

I also need the array in the script as I am not gathering it from a database or anything like that.

I am pretty green when it comes to javascript and google maps api, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function createMap(lat, lng, zoomVal) {
 var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),    
 zoom: zoomVal,   
 scrollwheel: false,  
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
}; 
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


var myLatlnglow = new google.maps.LatLng(23.654332,-79.387867);

var markerlow1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlnglow,
    icon: 'images/map-dot.png',
    map: map,
    url: '#',
    title: 'Name'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerlow1, 'click', function() {
window.location.href = markerlow1.url;
});


var myLatlnglow = new google.maps.LatLng(23.688458,-79.300619);

var markerlow = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlnglow,
    icon: 'images/map-dot.png',
    map: map,
    url: '#',
    title: 'Name'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerlow, 'click', function() {
window.location.href = markerlow.url;
});


}

var map;
function initialize() { 
 createMap(23.668493, -29.410812,12);
  if(navigator.geolocation) {  
  success = function(position) {    
 createMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude,13);  
};   
error = function() {
 createMap(23.648493, -29.410812,12); 
}    
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);  
} 
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to create and organize markers. For a tailored answer, explain how your data is organized, and how you wish to manipulate them. How is the input data formatted? Do you plan on entering the markers data directly in the JavaScript or pulling it from an external source like a database or JSON source?

Comment: @MaryAnne Thanks for your reply, not sure if I edited my question appropriately but I would like to enter the marker data directly in the JavaScript. I know for optimization sake I should be using some sort of table or database, but I am frighteningly inexperienced with databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would make an object of objects for the sake of readability. If you must have efficiency, and want to save space and typing, replace the object with an array and address the data by index (0,1,2...)

Here's [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/166/)

```
    // inside function createMap(...)
      ...
    markerData = {
        bing: {
            lat: 23.654332,
            lng: -79.387867,
            icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png",
            url: "http://www.bing.com/",
            title: "some search engine"
        },
        yahoo: {
            lat: 23.688458,
            lng: -79.300619,
            icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png",
            url: "http://www.yahoo.com/",
            title: "Great free games"
        }
    };

    for (markerId in markerData) {
        markers[markerId] = createMarker(markerData[markerId]);
    }

    markers['bing'].setTitle("new title");
}

function createMarker(data) {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        icon: data.icon,
        map: map,
        title: data.title
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        window.location.href = data.url;
    });

    return marker;
}
```

It should also help later to save the references to the created markers, I'm using the global object `markers` and the same IDs.

```
var map;
var markers = {};
```

If you later need to change a marker property it is accessible through `markers`.

```
   markers['bing'].setTitle("new title");
```